# The physical and spiritual halves of man in the Yerushalmi

Tags: sources-mekorot, soul, talmud-yerushalmi, maseches-kilayim

In the entry "Soul: Jewish Concept" on [Encyclopedia.com](https://www.encyclopedia.com/environment/encyclopedias-almanacs-transcripts-and-maps/soul-jewish-concept#:%7E:text=The%20close%20connection,attributed%20to%20God.) it states the following apparently based on the Yerushalmi:

> "The close connection between soul and body characteristic of the biblical worldview is continued in the rabbinic literature. The Palestinian Talmud (J.T., Kil. 8.4, 31c) attributes the origin of different portions of the physical body to human parents, while the spirit, life, and soul are attributed to God."

I gather that the Kil. is short for Kil'ayim, but I was unable to find any such idea in Yerushalmi Kil'ayim 8:4. Does anyone know where this idea appears in the Yerushalmi? A link to Sefaria or a similar site would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to be from [Yerushalmi Kilayim 8:3](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Jerusalem_Talmud_Kilayim.8.3.7?lang=bi):

> הַלּוֹבֶן מִן הָאִישׁ שֶׁמִּמֶּנּוּ מוֹחַ וַעֲצָמוֹת וְהַגִּידִים. וְהַאוֹדֶם מִן הָאִשָּׁה שֶׁמִּמֶּנָּה הָעוֹר וְהַבָּשָׂר וְהַדָּם. וְהָרוּחַ וְהַנֶּפֶשׁ וְהַנְּשָׁמָה מִשֶּׁל הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא. וּשְׁלָשְׁתָּן שׁוּתָפִין בּוֹ.

Comment: Thanks! [15 char]